# Getting time interval from formatted time strings

Tags: ruby

I have two variables `time_before` and `time_after` like below:

```
time_before = Time.now.strftime("%H%M%S")
time_after = Time.now.strftime("%H%M%S")
```

I want to get the time interval in seconds between `time_before` and `time_after` assigned at different times. Anybody please guide me a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
time_before = Time.now.strftime("%H%M%S")
sleep(1)
time_after = Time.now.strftime("%H%M%S")

[time_before, time_after]
.map{|s| Time.parse(s.scan(/\d\d/).join(":"))}
.tap{|t1, t2| puts t2 - t1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
time_before = Time.now
...
time_after = Time.now

puts "before #{time_before.strftime('%H%M%S')}"
puts "after #{time_before.strftime('%H%M%S')}"
puts "elapsed (seconds): #{time_after - time_before}" 
# its already in seconds, with fractional
puts "#{'%.0f' % (time_after - time_before)}" # just whole seconds
```